# Подсчёт суммы в цикле с условием выхода

Tags: математика, matlab

Необходимо написать функцию для решения этого примера:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня проблема с функцией:

```
function array = sumx(x)
    array = zeros(1, length(x));

    for i = 1:length(x)
        s = 0;
        k = 0;

        while true 
            temp = x(i)^k / factorial(k);           

            if abs(temp) > s
                s = s + temp;
            else
                break;
            end
        end

        array(i) = s;
    end
end
```

При `x = 0:1:5` выводит вектор из шести единиц, не думаю что так должно быть. Наверное, я неправильно понял математическую часть задания. В чём может быть дело?

Comment: Оператор цикла с условием завершения - это не For. Используйте While или Do..Loop - смотря что есть в матлабе. И храните/используйте значение предыдущего слагаемого для получения следующего: `a(i) = a(i-1) * x / i`. Кстати, заданная точность тоже должна быть параметром функции.

Comment: @Akina, В Matlab нет do while, только for и while, которые проверяют условие перед выполнением тела цикла.

Comment: Значит, `WHILE (eps<member) member=member*x/k++; sumx+=member; end;`. И потом - от тебя просят сумму, а не суммируемый ряд, зачем ты копишь массив? Ну и - почему ты организуешь цикл по `i`, если с вычислениях используешь `k`?

Comment: @Akina, во-первых, `while()` сразу же проверит условие, а мне нужна проверка после первой итерации, во-вторых, в Matlab нет оператора инкремента/декремента, в-третьих, в Matlab нет оператора `+=`. Добавил ответ.

Comment: *while() сразу же проверит условие, а мне нужна проверка после первой итерации* Ну будет странно, если заданная точность больше первого члена последовательности... *в Matlab нет оператора* Возможность складывать - есть? есть... что с чем сложить - понятно? надеюсь, понятно...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделал так:

```
function list = sumx(x)
    list = [];

    k = 0;
    while true
        temp = sum(x.^k ./ factorial(k));
        k = k + 1;

        if k > 1
            if abs(temp) <= list(k - 1)         
                break;
            else
                list = [list, temp];
            end
        else
            list = [list, temp];
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: А сможет твоя программа просчитать, скажем, 2000 членов прогрессии при x=500? Или получишь overflow? А ведь любой из членов прогрессии и любое промежуточное значение суммы не выходят за рамки Double...

Comment: @Akina, Я не силён в Matlab, и я не понял как сделать ваш вариант. Вы можете добавить свой ответ и если он посчитает 2000 членов прогрессии при x=500 без overflow, то я отмечу его как правильный.

Comment: Вместо `temp = sum(x.^k ./ factorial(k));` вставьте типа `nextmember=nextmember*x/k; summ=summ+nexmember;`. *если он посчитает 2000 членов прогрессии при x=500 без overflow* На VBA - посчитал как делать нечего... впрочем, из-за отсутствия длинной арифметики половина работы была вхолостую, но сам факт...